# C# Math.Round(4.25,1) rounds it to 4.2 instead of 4.3 What is wrong?

Tags: c#, rounding

```
decimal avg = Math.Round(4.25,1);
```

gives 4.2 ; I want 4.3 what should be done?

Comment: Check [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=net-7.0#system-math-round(system-double-system-int32)), specifically the bit about midpoint rounding!

Comment: If you want to round up a number, use `Math.Ceiling()`

Comment: It gives a compiler error because a double is not a decimal

Comment: Change the midpoint rounding mode to `AwayFromZero`, it rounds to evens by default for doubles and decimals.

Comment: `decimal avg = Math.Round(4.25m, 1, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);` (note `4.25m` as well - if you want to get `decimal` you should provide `decimal` input)

Comment: in programming you should never assume. there are reference manuals for a reason.

Comment: MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
decimal avg = (decimal)Math.Round(4.251, 1, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

You want one digit and if it's at 4.25 you want 4.3.

Everything is explained in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=net-7.0#system-math-round(system-double-system-int32-system-midpointrounding)).